# Vaadin Calendar: How to allow HTML in event caption

Tags: java, javascript, html, calendar, vaadin

I would like to have HTML support in the caption of an vaadin calendar event.
HTML is allowed in the month view but not in the week View.
And is there a possibility to have a different caption in month and week view?

Comment: I extend the BasicEvent and set the caption to the wanted caption. If I enter HTML code, this Code is just processed in the month view and not in the week view. There are just the HTML tags shown in the month view.

Comment: Why has this question received 3 downvotes? It's a valid question and I've encountered the same problem.

Comment: Apparently it's a bug, I postet this question in the vaadin forum: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1529315

Comment: Do you mean week view like that https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.calendar.html#figure.components.calendar.daterange.monthly

Comment: the change was released (http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9030). please mark the question as solved if that fixed your porblem